# SQL Server CLR Assembly to Post Service Bus Message

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, message-queue

I have created a SQL Server Database Project in Visual Studio 2015, with the goal being that I want to publish an assembly to a local (non Azure) SQL database. The assembly is a SQL Function that will post a message to an Azure Service Bus. For that reason, I added a reference in the project to the Microsoft.ServiceBus dll. Other than that, it is a very basic project. (I could not add the Azure Service Bus via NuGet). The code contains a single function to post a message to a queue. The idea is that I want to have a function available in my database that accepts a service bus connection string, a queue name, and a message, and the assembly will post a message to the queue.

When I try to run the publish SQL file generated, SQL complains that:

> Msg 6503, Level 16, State 12, Line 47 Assembly 'microsoft.servicebus,
>   version=3.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=31bf3856ad364e35.'
>   was not found in the SQL catalog.

How do I get SQL to recognize that my assembly also needs to use the ServiceBus dll?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to use `CREATE ASSEMBLY` for assemblies your code depends on.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration/database-objects/supported-net-framework-libraries. Note that `Microsfot.Servicebus` is not supported and will require additional permissions sets (i.e. external access, unsafe).

Comment: Thank you very much, Dan. Because the ServiceBus dll is not trusted, I reworked the  code to not use the dll, but instead use a webClient POST to the send the message. All of the required libraries to do that were native to the base SQL Project, and everything is working like a charm.

Comment: FWIW, an alternative approach is to use NServiceBus to bridge between "queues" in SQL Server and queues in Azure Service Bus. For example, you can "send" messages within the database (https://docs.particular.net/samples/sqltransport/native-integration/#sending-from-within-the-database) and then use https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/bridge/ to bridge those messages to Azure Service Bus.